# Can't connect to local MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql

I have a account page configured like the following;

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["myusername"])){
```

> then show some login form

else connect to database and show the logged user's details. The page displayes the form but with some mysql errors at the bottom.

[image: Mysql error]

the issue is that at this point the condition is just to show the form, not connect to mysql.

Now enter username: demo@demo.com / password: demo (the font is white, i haven't fixed that yet.) the website is http://auto-sal.es/account.php

and you will see that everything works okay.
[image: logged]

Can anyone please help me find out what the issue is.

here is the code for the account page.

```
<?php include("header.php"); ?>
<body id="account">
<div id="wholewrap">
<div id="bodywrap">
<div id="content">

<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["myusername"])){
$form = '
<h1>Members section</h1>
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Username</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="mypassword" type="text" id="mypassword"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>';
echo $form;
}
else
include("conn.php");
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE cus_id = '$cus_id';";
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
mysql_error();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
$layout='
<h1>Your details</h1>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="308" valign="top"><p>Name:</p></td>
    <td width="308" valign="top"><p>' . $row['name'] . '</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="308" valign="top"><p>DOB:</p></td>
    <td width="308" valign="top"><p>' . $row['dob'] . '</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="308" valign="top"><p>Address:</p></td>
    <td width="308" valign="top"><p>' . $row['address'] . '</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="308" valign="top"><p>Email:</p></td>
    <td width="308" valign="top"><p>' . $row['email'] . '</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="308" valign="top"><p>Telephone:</p></td>
    <td width="308" valign="top"><p>' . $row['telephone'] . '</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="308" valign="top"><p>Join date:</p></td>
    <td width="308" valign="top"><p>' . $row['join_date'] . '</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="308" valign="top"><p>Last access:</p></td>
    <td width="308" valign="top"><p>' . $row['last_access'] . '</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>';
echo $layout;
}
mysql_close();
    ?>
</div>  <!-- content #end -->
<div id="sidebar">
<h1>Sidebar</h1>
</div>  <!-- sidebar #end -->
</div>  <!-- bodywrap #end -->
</div>  <!-- wholewrap #end -->
<?php include("footer.php");?>
```

**connection contents**

```
<?php
$host="xxx"; // Host name 
$username="xxxx"; // Mysql username 
$password="xxx"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="xxx"; // Database name 
$name=$_SESSION['name'];
$cus_id=$_SESSION['cus_id'];

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
?>
```

Comment: What are the contents of `conn.php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at these lines of your code:

```
else
   include("conn.php");
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE cus_id = '$cus_id';";
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
```

Your code will only include the connection file (conn.php) if $_SESSION["myusername"] is set.
you need to wrap all the query code in the else section between `{ ... }`

Comment: Thanks, i got it, didnt realise i had to wrap after else {